# Motorola LS1203 Barcode Scanner

Tags: java, serial-port, barcode

I'm using a Motorola LS1203 Barcode Scanner and trying to connect it to a Java program.

I can get it working through a USB cable emulating a keyboard and that prints to notepad fine, and I could just capture that information, but the Java program would have to have focus.

I'd much prefer to have it sent over RS232 emulation (because I could then just have Java run an eventListener over the COM port), but I have no serial port on the computer it's supposed to be connected to, because it's a laptop. Is there a way of getting the HID keyboard emulator to appear as a COM devide over RS232 without a serial cable?

Comment: Most "old-fashion" devices connected to USB has built-in emulation of serial port. Did you checked that there really don't get up a serial COM device when you plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This model DOES support RS232 emulation via USB. There is a program on Motorola's website to allow you to change settings.

http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Bar+Code+Scanning/General+Purpose+Scanners/LS1203_US-EN

Download the 123Scan utility, and print off the configuration options for the barcode by following the instructions on the program. This will allow you to select Keyboard Emulation or COM Port Emulation. From there, it can be read through the serial port at 9600 baud.

Oh, and there's also no driver for 64 bit windows, I could only get it working on XP32bit, that might save someone else some time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that particular model supports what you are looking for (plug in USB and have it show up as a serial device on the OS). What you could do is buy an inexpensive off the shelf  USB-to-serial port dongle which would give your laptop a serial port.

One like this should work: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812107108

Then you would need the LS1203 serial interface cable to attach the LS1203 to the serial port.